# foreach input multidimensional array

Tags: jquery, multidimensional-array

I have the following html

```
<input type="checkbox" name="array[0][count]" value="1"/>
<input type="hidden" data-price="50" name="array[0][id]" value="1"/>

<input type="checkbox" name="array[1][count]" value="5"/>
<input type="hidden" data-price="20" name="array[1][id]" value="2"/>

.....
```

I want to calculate the sum of `data-price` using jQuery with the formula

```
foreach extra {
    price += extra[id][data-price] * extra[count]
}

//not actual code, just a representation of the result needed
```

So far I was able to collect all the inputs using

```
$('input[name^="array"]').each(function() {
    console.log($(this));
});
```

But I have no idea how to proceed further. Any help appreciated. If you can point me to a better way to structure the html array, I'm ok with that.

Comment: You want to calculate the sum of data-price: how? I am asking because there seems to be a relationship between each checkbox and the adjacent hidden input holding the data-price. So ***do you want to calculate the sum of data-price of all checked checkboxes or just simply all the checkboxes: irrespective of whether any is checked or not?***

Comment: I know how to check whether a checkbox is checked or not, but yes, I want to calculate the sum of all `:checked` inputs, each multiplied by the corresponding `count`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are very close. All you need to do is get the price from the attribute now.

```
$(this).attr("data-price");
```

I noticed not all `'input[name^="array"]'` have data attribute, so you need to check if it exists before adding or just rename the ones with the actual data attribute.

Below code works fine

```
$('input[name^="array"]').each(function() {

var dPrice =$(this).attr("data-price");
if(dPrice){ //check if data-price exists for the input
  price+= parseInt($(this).attr("data-price"),10);
  }
});
```

[Here's a working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4793z8w9/)

Once you have the attribute, apply your formula and voila! You're done

**UPDATE from comments**:

While creating the checkbox from array, you do something like

```
<input type="hidden" data-price="50" name="array[0][id]" data-quantity=[count] value="1"/>
```

and then use the above code and get the `data-quantity` attribute and use it in your formula

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know how to get the attribute, the question is how to get the multiplayer (count) corresponding to that price?

Comment: Oh, sorry I misunderstood the question. Do you have any restriction with data attributes? I would make a new data attribute `data-quantity` and use that? Does that work for you?

Comment: I'm completely free to change the HTML as best suits the needed result.

Comment: While creating the checkbox from array, cant you do something like `<input type="hidden" data-price="50" name="array[0][id]" data-quantity=[count] value="1"/>` and then use the above code and get the `data-quantity` attibute and use in your formula

Comment: Minutes ago I came up with a similar solution (to change the data-count of input when changed) and then to use your code to calculate. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is chance a little things.

Frist, in html join the input checkbox with the hidden field:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="array[]" data-price="50" value="1"/>

<input type="checkbox" name="array[]" data-price="20" value="5"/>
```

Secund, let the js like this:

```
var total = 0;
$('input[name^="array"]').each(function() {
    if($(this)[0].checked){
        total += $(this).attr("data-price")  * $(this).attr("value");
    }
});
```

If you do not want to check with the checkboxes are checked remove the if.

If total become a string so use the parseInt

[See in Fiddle working](https://jsfiddle.net/brunoracosta/w0dc29ya/5/)

**If you want to maintain the html like yours**

Only change one thing put position in a Attribute. HTML::

```
<input type="checkbox" name="array2[count]" data-pos="0" value="1"/>
<input type="hidden" data-price="50" name="array2[id][0]" value="1"/>

<input type="checkbox" name="array2[count]" data-pos="1" value="5"/>
<input type="hidden" data-price="20" name="array2[id][1]" value="2"/>
```

The js wil be like that:

```
    var total2 = 0;

  $('input[name^="array2[count]"]').each(function() {
    if($(this)[0].checked){
        var pos = $(this).attr("data-pos");
        total2 += $('input[name^="array2[id]['+pos+']"]').attr("data-price")  * $(this).attr("value");
    }
```

});

The both code are in the same fiddle Test 1 is frist example and the Test 2 is this example

[See in Fiddle working](https://jsfiddle.net/brunoracosta/w0dc29ya/5/)